# How to set hydra's parameter HYDRA_FULL_ERROR?

Tags: python, pytorch, fb-hydra

When I use hydra in a python pytorch project, the operation result prompt “Set the environment variable HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 for a complete stack trace.”
But i don't konw how to set it.

Comment: How are you running your project? For shell run as `HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 ./my_project.py`.

Answer (score 5):

You set an environment variable in the shell.
For a specific run:

```sh
$ HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1 python foo.py
```

Or for all runs in this shell session:

```sh
$ export HYDRA_FULL_ERROR=1
$ python foo.py
```

However, you shouldn't normally need to set it. This is more of a debugging backdoor in case of issues with Hydra itself.
If you hit a case where you can only understand your issue after setting HYDRA_FULL_ERROR, please file an issue.